# Facebook Mark as Paid Button API

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am trying to build my own custom Facebook messenger with [Facebook Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform).

*I came across a problem on what API endpoint to recording down the amount of sales closed in this conversation.*

Below is what happen in real messenger from our Facebook business page message window to customer.
There is a currency button in the messenger. after we clicked we can enter the total sales amount of this conversation.

[image]

This window will popup , we can enter the amount here.

[image]

*I am struggling on finding an API endpoint to record down this amount. So the ads manager can record ROAS of those sales going through conversation with manual bank-in payment.*

**Do Facebook provide endpoint for this action?**

**Or do we have alternative way/workaround method to achieve the same goal?**